# Installing InfluxDB on Linode Ubuntu

Tags: influxdb

I have a 32 bit Ubuntu on Linode, confirmed by:

```
~$ uname -m
i686
```

Following the install instructions I get:

```
~$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/influxdb/influxdb_latest_i686.deb
...
Length: 16572810 (16M) [binary/octet-stream]
Saving to: `influxdb_latest_i686.deb'
100%[======================================>] 16,572,810  2.43M/s   in 7.3s
2015-03-31 15:59:28 (2.16 MB/s) - `influxdb_latest_i686.deb' saved       

~$ sudo dpkg -i influxdb_latest_i686.deb
dpkg: error processing influxdb_latest_i686.deb (--install):
package architecture (i686) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
influxdb_latest_i686.deb
```

I tried the amd64 package as well, and got the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB no longer provides i386 binaries, you would need to compile from sources.
I managed to install 0.8 with `dpkg -i --force-architecture  influxdb_0.8.8_i686.deb` but 0.9 won't work

From https://influxdata.com/downloads/

> About 32-Bit Packages
>
> The industry is gradually moving away from
>   support for 32-bit x86 architectures so we do not provide packaged
>   32-bit binaries. However, we do endeavour to ensure the source can be
>   compiled for a 32-bit x86 architecture at all times. To that end our
>   CI system currently compiles 32-bit binaries and runs the unit test
>   suite against the 32-bit build, in addition to the main 64-bit build.
>   If compilation or unit testing for 32-bit architecture fails, we fix
>   it.